# python 'AxesSubplot' has no attribute sns

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

plt.style.use('seaborn')

np.random.seed(78951257)
data = np.random.randn(2, 100)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(5, 5))
axs[0, 0].hist(data[0])
axs[1, 0].plot(data[0], data[1])
axs[0, 1].sns.kdeplot(data[0], data[1], cmap="Red", shade=True)
axs[1, 1].hist2d(data[0], data[1])

plt.show()
```

What I want is to show all four of these graphs. However when I want the graph

```
axs[0, 1].sns.kdeplot(data[0], data[1], cmap="Red", shade=True)
```

It says that there is an error saying that AxesSubplot has no attribute 'kdeplot'. I imported my seaborn style as sns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seaborn is a module, so it isn't called as you have there. Something like this:

```
sns.kdeplot(data[0], data[1], cmap="Reds", shade=True, ax=axs[0,1])
```

should do the trick. Note also that "Red" is not a colormap, but "Reds" is.

[image]